# tor on debian: how does the user fallback work?

Tags: debian, tor

I cannot get my head around a strange behaviour I observed on my Debian 6 system today. When I run tor, either via `/etc/init.d/tor` or directly via `/sbin/tor`, the new tor process drops its root privileges and sets its uid to the one of the `debian-tor` - user. Whilst this is a good thing, I fail to see why the application actually does so. My /etc/tor/torrc does not contain a corresponding `User`-configuration-entry. How does tor know to which uid it should fall back in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

`debian-tor` is hardcoded in the Tor executable by a Debian patch.

Run `apt-get source tor` and look in `tor-0.2.1.30/debian/patches/06_add_compile_time_defaults.dpatch`.